# Getting WebApi and Areas to play nicely

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-areas

I'm using Martin Deviller's [tutorial](http://blogs.infosupport.com/asp-net-mvc-4-rc-getting-webapi-and-areas-to-play-nicely) to get MVC4's Web API working with Areas. I believe I've followed the instructions exactly, but GetControllerType throws the following exception when accessing "http://localhost/API/user":

```
Value cannot be null. Parameter name: controllerType
```

Does anyone have any ideas what could be causing this? This is what I've placed in my Area Registration file:

```
context.MapHttpRoute(
    name: "API_default",
    routeTemplate: "API/{controller}/{id}",
    defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
);
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see you are trying to access the route of the application without the area. Do you need areas or not?

If you are trying to follow the example then the Area registration would make the url "http://localhost/administration/API/user". Does this work?

```
    context.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
        name: "Administration_DefaultApi",
        routeTemplate: "Administration/api/{controller}/{id}",
        defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
    );
```

Comment: API is the name of my area. How can I set the route accordingly?

Comment: API is the Area name by default for all classes that inherit from API controller. You don't have to do any extra work with Area Registration to make your ApiController accessible under /api/user. It works straight out of the box that way.

Comment: I just tried placing my UserController in Areas/API/Controllers but I get a 404. Have I misunderstood? Thanks for your help so far.

Comment: There is no need for the API folder. Your ApiController can reside in the root: /Controllers or in your area: /Areas/Admin/Controllers. In either case it is always addressable under the API url path: localhost/api/user.